# React nested routers not rendering properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to get these nested routers working for awhile now but, I can't figure it out.

Here is the parent route:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route
              path="/home"
              component={() => <Home user={this.state.user} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/login"
              component={() => <Login setUser={this.setUser} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the home component:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.user) {
      return (
        <div className="bg">
          <AppContainer firstName={this.state.user.firstName} />
          <NavBar />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="bg">
          <AppContainer />
          <NavBar />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the AppContainer Component

```
<div>
      <div className="container">
        <SideNav firstName={props.firstName} />
        <AppContent />
      </div>
      <div className="blur_img"></div>
    </div>
```

Lastly, here is the AppContent Component

```
 <div className="appContent">
      <Route exact component={NoSelection}></Route>
      <Route path="home/entries" component={AllEntries} />
    </div>
```

The first route is working fine but the second one does not render.
home/entries url does not change the NoSelection component to the AllEntries, it just stays the same.

I probably could have though of a better layout for this tbh.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you haven't got a path for the first Route in the AppContent Container.

So every url is gonna match with the {noSelection} Route, and so you're stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route
    path="/home"
    render={(routeProps) => <Home user={this.state.user} />} // <= You need this
/>
<Route
   path="/login"
   render={(routeProps) => <Login setUser={this.setUser} />} // <= You need this
/>
```

api : https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

description render func :
This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above.
Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop function has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop.